# Perl or Awk: Match Movie run times greater than 5 hours

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I need to re-catalog all movies with runtimes greater than 5 hours.

Sample data:

```
239835<TAB> 92075<TAB>Moonlighting, seasons one and two<TAB>NVIDEO<TAB>DVD<TAB>6 videodiscs (approximately 1200 min.) :
628328  180001  7th heaven. NVIDEO  DVD 5 videodiscs (15 hr., 57 min.) :
773429  291072  Veronica Mars.  NVIDEO  DVD 6 videodiscs (842 min.) :
789908  379843  Castle in the Sky   NVIDEO  JDVD    2 videodiscs (approximately 125 min.) :
856287  208624  The Munsters.   NVIDEO  DVD 12 videodiscs (approximately 33 hr.) :
1076125 254085  From up on Poppy Hill (Rated PG)    NVIDEO  JDVD    2 videodiscs (91 min.) :
1154016 264851  Columbo.    NVIDEO  DVD 5 videodiscs (725 min.) :
1217001 113980  CSI, crime scene investigation. NVIDEO  DVD 5 videodiscs (approximately 732 min.) :
1227803 280535  Seattle Seahawks    NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (500 min.) :
1227804 280535  Seattle Seahawks    NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (500 min.) :
1287497 293511  Seattle Seahawks :  NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (400 min.) :
1287499 293511  Seattle Seahawks :  NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (400 min.) :
1367994 228775  Spongebob Squarepants.  NVIDEO  JDVD    4 videodiscs (469 min.) :
1368002 257248  SpongeBob SquarePants.  NVIDEO  JDVD    4 videodiscs (589 min.) :
```

Is there a quick perl or awk snippet or one-liner that would:
* Print the whole line if
* # of "min" is greater than 300 or
* # of "hr(s)" is greater than 5

Something like:

```
perl -F\\t -ane 'print if $F[6] <substring or capture group representing minutes> > 300' file.csv
```

Getter closer with `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' '$6 ~ /^.*\(.*[3-9][[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]+min.*\)/ {print}' minutes.csv
```

REGEX patterns:
Minutes greater than 300:
`/^.*\(.*[[:space:]][3-9][[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]+min.*\)/`

Minutes greater than 1000:
`/^.*\(.*[[:digit:]]{4,}[[:space:]]+min.*\)/`

Hours greater than 5:
`/^.*\(.*[[:space:]][5-9]{1}[[:space:]]+hr.*\)/`

Hours greater than 10:
`/^.*\(.*[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{4}[[:space:]]+hr.*\)/`

Is there a simpler more concise way?

Comment: Tab separated data doesn't play well with SO. Where are the columns separated in that example?

Comment: Will add them on the first line so you can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to do it all with one monster regular expression, I think splitting it up into a couple of different ones is more readable and easier to understand when you come back to it later. No need to feed the stereotype of perl looking like line noise...

```
$ perl -F\\t -ane 'print if ($F[5] =~ /(\d+) hr\./ && $1 > 5) || ($F[5] =~ /(\d+) min\./ && $1 > 300)' input.tsv
```

This extracts the numbers before `hr.` or `min.` in the sixth column (And only that one in case a matching string also appears in the name column) and compares them to see if they're greater than 5 or 300 respectively, and only prints those matching lines.

Comment: This version seems to be more accurate, though I couldn't say why. The other answer produces less results. I wonder if the expression is getting tripped up on false positives somehow.

Comment: @Bubnoff Yeah, that other perl answer doesn't properly capture the numbers from a lot of strings. In the Moonlighting line, for example, everything between the parenthesis ended up matching the very last `.*?` in the RE with everything else before it matching 0-length substrings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex with capture groups with perl:

```
> perl -ne'/\(.*?(?:(\d+) hr\.)?.*?(?:(\d+) min\.)?.*?\)/&&($1>5||$2>300)&&print' catalog
628328  180001  7th heaven. NVIDEO  DVD 5 videodiscs (15 hr., 57 min.) :
773429  291072  Veronica Mars.  NVIDEO  DVD 6 videodiscs (842 min.) :
1154016 264851  Columbo.    NVIDEO  DVD 5 videodiscs (725 min.) :
1227803 280535  Seattle Seahawks    NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (500 min.) :
1227804 280535  Seattle Seahawks    NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (500 min.) :
1287497 293511  Seattle Seahawks :  NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (400 min.) :
1287499 293511  Seattle Seahawks :  NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (400 min.) :
1367994 228775  Spongebob Squarepants.  NVIDEO  JDVD    4 videodiscs (469 min.) :
1368002 257248  SpongeBob SquarePants.  NVIDEO  JDVD    4 videodiscs (589 min.) :
```

Comment: @bihsing This works! Would you be so kind as to break down the `regex` for me? I see the capture groups indicated by the parens and I get the `.*?` syntax, but what about the `?:`?

Comment: Glad to be of help. `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. Since we only want to capture the numbers, all the other groups should be made non-capturing. The non-capturing groups here are used to group the entire verbiage of `xx hr.` or `yy min.` together so that we can use the `?` quantifier to make both of them optional.

Comment: OP pointed out elsewhere that this version doesn't print a number of lines of the sample data that it should, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Since 5 hours is 300 mins you don't need to treat them separately just convert any hours and/or mins specification into mins. Using any awk:

```
awk -F'\t' '
    {
        hrs  = ( match($6,/[0-9]+ hr/)  ? substr($6,RSTART)+0 : 0 )
        mins = ( match($6,/[0-9]+ min/) ? substr($6,RSTART)+0 : 0 )
    }
    (hrs*60 + mins) > 300
' file
```

but you could write it as 2 separate tests if you prefer:

```
awk -F'\t' '
    {
        hrs  = ( match($6,/[0-9]+ hr/)  ? substr($6,RSTART)+0 : 0 )
        mins = ( match($6,/[0-9]+ min/) ? substr($6,RSTART)+0 : 0 )
    }
    (hrs > 5) || (mins > 300)
' file
```

Comment: How would you write this with modern GAWK? I was not able to get capture groups working with `match($6, /REGEX/ , a)` ..etc. it was ignoring `{3,}` type operators.

Comment: If I was writing it for gawk only the only change I'd make would be to turn `hrs  = ( match($6,/[0-9]+ hr/)  ? substr($6,RSTART)+0 : 0 )` into `match($6,/[0-9]+ hr/,a); hrs=a[0]+0` and similar for mins. I don't know where you're thinking a `{3,}` would come in.

Comment: You're right, in this particular example `{3,}` would not be useful. In my tests, [ with mistaken assumptions, as you point out ], it did not work and my question is more general. This is a generic REGEX construct and didn't work as expected in the GAWK `match($6,/[0-9]{3,} hr/,a)` construct. I agree that it was unnecessary but am wondering why it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: In what way did it "not work"? Your input doesn't contain any strings of 3-or-more digits in the 6th field - did you think it does and are surprised when gawk can't find it? Or did you have some different input you're running that against? Or did you think `[0-9]{3,}` meant something other than `3 or more digits`?

Comment: In some of the runtime strings, you'd get a string like this: `1250 min`. Your solution demonstrates that using a construct such as `{3,}` is unnecessary, however, when used *without* the `match` construct the `{3,}` works as expected -- within the `match` construct it only pulls records with `1` digit followed by min. I was just curious as to whether I needed escapes ...etc. It's not a big deal and don't want to take up your time. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome and it's no trouble. No you don't need escapes. I can't imagine what the issue is given when you've told me so far since to any tool than handles regexps either `{3,}` means `a repetition of 3 or more` or it means literally `the string "{3,}"` and neither of those would match `1 min` or similar as you're saying you see when you run whatever code you're running against whatever input you're running it against. So I'd need to see a concrete example. Please feel free to post a new question with it's own [mcve] of sample input, expected output and code if you'd like help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awk`:

```
> awk -F'[^0-9]+' '/min\./&&$(NF-1)>300||/hr\./&&$(NF-/min\./-1)>5' catalog
239835  92075   Moonlighting, seasons one and two   NVIDEO  DVD 6 videodiscs (approximately 1200 min.) :
628328  180001  7th heaven. NVIDEO  DVD 5 videodiscs (15 hr., 57 min.) :
773429  291072  Veronica Mars.  NVIDEO  DVD 6 videodiscs (842 min.) :
856287  208624  The Munsters.   NVIDEO  DVD 12 videodiscs (approximately 33 hr.) :
1154016 264851  Columbo.    NVIDEO  DVD 5 videodiscs (725 min.) :
1217001 113980  CSI, crime scene investigation. NVIDEO  DVD 5 videodiscs (approximately 732 min.) :
1227803 280535  Seattle Seahawks    NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (500 min.) :
1227804 280535  Seattle Seahawks    NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (500 min.) :
1287497 293511  Seattle Seahawks :  NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (400 min.) :
1287499 293511  Seattle Seahawks :  NVIDEO  DVD 3 videodiscs (400 min.) :
1367994 228775  Spongebob Squarepants.  NVIDEO  JDVD    4 videodiscs (469 min.) :
1368002 257248  SpongeBob SquarePants.  NVIDEO  JDVD    4 videodiscs (589 min.) :
```

Answer (score 0):

let your data in 'd' file,

```
perl -F"\(|\)" -ane '$t=@F[$#F-1]; $t =~ s/.*?(\d+\s*(?:min|hr.)).*/\1/; if($t =~ /min/ && $t>300 or $t =~ /hr./ && $t>5) {print "@F\n"}' d
```